# Rendering latin characters: R markdown pandoc tables

Tags: r, markdown, pandoc

I'm using R on Windows and generating a Word output (.docx) from a markdown file.

I'm trying to print a table using pandoc.table (I tried kable, but it doesn't give me the layout controls I need). The problem is: it renders latin characters adequately if they are in the column names, but not if they are values in the data frame.

Example:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(pander)
dados <- data.frame(Matriz = c("Solo", "Água", "Vapor de\nSolo"),
                    Ponto = c("P-1", "P-2", "P-3"),
                    Resultado = c(10000, 5.45, NA))
names(dados) <- c("**Matriz**", "Ponto\nAmostração", "***Resultado (ug/L)***")
pandoc.table(dados, caption="Tabela de teste")
```
````

The result comes out like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    **Matriz**      Ponto       ***Resultado (ug/L)***
                  Amostração                          
    ------------ ------------ ------------------------
    Solo            NFS-22                       10000

    Ãgua           NFS-22                        5.45

    Vapor          NF-VP-01                           
    de                                                
    Solo                                              
    --------------------------------------------------
```

So, as you see, the word "Amostração" (a column name) came out just fine, while "Água" (a value in a data frame) was messed up.